# Django-Q schedule nonetype error with custom function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create some scheduled tasks in my Django project using Django-Q. The problem is that every schedule task fails raising next exception:

```
'NoneType' object is not callable : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/gamesquare-pre/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_q/cluster.py", line 432, in worker
res = f(*task["args"], **task["kwargs"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The schedule is called like:

```py
from django_q.tasks import schedule

schedule('orders.mails.product', 2, 2, schedule_type='O')
```

Then, in **mails.py** (same folder) I have the method product defined:

```
def product(x, y)
    return x * y
```

My Django-Q's configuration in **settings.py**:

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'qclust',
    'workers': config('Q_CLUSTER_WORKERS', cast=int),
    'timeout': 20,
    'cpu_affinity': 1,
    'save_limit': 50,
    'queue_limit': 100,
    'redis': {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

your path or function seems to be missing or wrong
orders.mails.product

make sure that exists

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing a line of code at the beginning to import the method **product**:

```
from .mails import product
```

Then when you create the schedule it would look like this:

```
schedule(product, 2, 2, schedule_type='O')
```